# Running total (COUNT) SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, cumulative-sum

I currently have this result

```
 ID Code
 1  AAA12
 2  F5
 3  GOFK568
 4  G77
 5  JLKJ4
 6  FOG0
```

Now what i want to do is to create a third column that keeps a running total for codes that are above 4 in length.

Now, i have this code that gives me the sum of the code with above 4 in length.

```
 SELECT * ,
 SUM(CASE WHEN LENGTH(CODE) > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Count]
 FROM Table1;
```

But this gives me this result

```
 ID Code    Count
 1  AAA12   3
```

I am looking for a result like this

```
 ID Code    Running_Total
 1  AAA12         1
 2  F5            1
 3  GOFK568       2
 4  G77           2
 5  JLKJ4         3
 6  FOG0          3
```

I was working on something similar to this

```
 SELECT * ,
 CASE WHEN LENGTH(CODE) > 4 THEN (SUM(Code) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)) ELSE END 
 AS [Count]
 FROM Table1;
```

But it still doesn't give me a running total.

I have an SQL Fiddle page

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2746c/18

Any help would be great

Comment: Use double quotes (or square brackets) for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"Count"` or `[Count]`. Single quotes are for string literals.

Comment: @jarlh ok, edit made

Comment: You are using Mysql or Sql Server ?

Comment: @Pரதீப், how come you suspect MySQL? The subject says SQL Server, the tag as well, and the query looks like SQL Server. **Edit**: Now I see, the sqlfiddle...

Comment: @jarlh sqlfiddle link was set to mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the case in the sum:

```
SELECT Table1.* ,
SUM(case when len(Code) > 4 then 1 else 0 end) OVER (order BY ID) as counted
FROM Table1;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Sql Server 2012+ you can use `Sum() Over(Order by)` function

```
SELECT Sum(CASE WHEN Len(code) > 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
         OVER(ORDER BY id)
FROM   Yourtable
```

for older versions

```
SELECT *
FROM   Yourtable a
       CROSS apply (SELECT Count(*)
                    FROM   Yourtable b
                    WHERE  a.ID >= b.ID
                           AND Len(code) > 4) cs (runn)
```

ANSI SQL method

```
SELECT ID,Code,
       (SELECT count(*)
        FROM   Yourtable  b
        WHERE  a.ID >= b.ID and char_length(code) > 4) AS runn
FROM   Yourtable a
```

Comment: ANSI SQL comments: The first query is valid ANSI SQL, but uses the non-core feature T611, "Elementary OLAP operations". The last query is _almost_ ANSI SQL compliant, you have to do `SELECT a.*, ...` to be fully compliant, ans switch from len() to char_length().

Comment: @jarlh - Good to know ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are some good and efficient answers here.
But in case you want to try different approach then try following query:

```
SELECT
t1.*,
(Select sum(r.cnt) from 
 (SELECT COUNT(t2.code) as cnt FROM table1 AS t2 
  WHERE t2.Id <= t1.Id 
  group by t2.code 
  having len(t11.code) > 4) r
) AS Count
FROM table1 AS t1;
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://rextester.com/IAIYIC7044)

Hope it helps!